# Xamarin Forms Error Deserializing Xml Data C#

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, deserialization, icollection

I'm trying to deserialize an XML file that exists on a local web server into objects of custom-types using c# classes in Xamarin Forms for use on an Android device.
I get an error during the deserialization process:

> "To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must
>   have an implementation of Add(Xamarin.Forms.Element) at all levels of
>   their inheritance hierarchy."

Why am I getting this error? Where do I put the Add method and Why?

I have tried adding an empty Add method on every single serializable class - this doesn't fix the issue.

This part of the code does the deserializing.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PartyData));
var reader = XmlReader.Create("192.168.0.14/SkillTreesDB.aspx");
partyData = xs.Deserialize(reader) as PartyData;
```

Some classes, including 'Skill' inherit from Xamarin.Forms Views.

Here's an example of part of one of the serialized classes that does so. Including one of its collections.

```
[Serializable]
public class Skill : StackLayout
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string name;
    [XmlAttribute("level")]
    public int level;
    [XmlAttribute("expToNext")]
    public int expToNext;
    [XmlAttribute("exp")]
    public int exp;
    [XmlAttribute("scaling")]
    public float scaling;
    [XmlArray("subSkills") , XmlArrayItem(typeof(SubSkill), ElementName = "subSkill")]
    public List<SubSkill> subSkills;
```

Comment: You should serialize data ... not UI elements

Comment: Noted.
Would that cause this issue specifically do you think?

Comment: why does a model class inherit from a UI class (StackLayout)?

Comment: *Would that cause this issue specifically do you think?* this: *Some classes, including 'Skill' inherit from Xamarin.Forms Views*

Comment: I'd also consider using json serialization instead of XML - its generally much easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I will change the serialized classes to basic representatives of raw data and then have the Views separately. I'll be back later to let you know guys know how it goes

Comment: I have followed the kind instructions given to me by Selvin
The original error has gone away. Now, I have a different error.
"Derived class must provide an implementation (NotSupportedException)"

Comment: you should probably post this as a new question with the appropriate details

Comment: Have opened a new question about the new problem arising
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738049/notsupportedexception-thrown-when-invoking-xmlserializers-constructor-in-xamari)