# NotSupportedException thrown when invoking XmlSerializer's constructor in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.forms, xml-serialization

On Xamarin Forms, the following syntax throws an Exception

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
}
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
         var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    }
}
```

While the following does not:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(int));
    }
}
```

The complete Exception text is

> Derived classed must provide an implementation (NotSupportedException)

On a console app, either expression works perfectly with no Exceptions thrown.
What is special about the usage of XmlSerializers on Xamarin Forms that makes the following expression illegal?

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeReferenceTypeWithAnEmptyConstructor));
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the following: 1) The full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any; 2) A [mcve] showing classes that reproduce the problem.  `XmlSerializer` messages are sometimes misleading so code that actually demonstrates the problem would be helpful.

Comment: I was able to make the code more verifiable and complete.
But I couldn't make it anymore minimal or find any additional Exception details.

Comment: what versions of the .NET framework are you using in your 2 examples?  They are probably not the same.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017 as my editor and the target framework when creating a new app defaults to 4.6.1
I'm not sure how to check it specifically for a Xamarin.Forms app, however.

Comment: The version of Xamarin I am using is 4.10.10.2 according to Visual Studio 2017's
Help > About Visual Studio

Comment: Apparently, Xamarin updates roll automatically into VS17 updates, so if the version could be a problem, then I will update it and check again.

Comment: fully updated Vs17 and still getting the same issue. The error isn't very descriptive.